# How to prove this function is not a surjection?

Tags: functions

Let $F: \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ be defined by 
$$F(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$$

How do I formally prove this is NOT a surjection?

Comment: When defined as a function from where to where?

Comment: Z x Z to Z is the answer to that

Comment: Are there ever any $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2-y^2=2$?

Comment: How can I formally prove that though? I think we need more than just a counterexample

Comment: You should state explicitly _in your question_ that $F$ is a function from $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$. This is a question about surjections, for heaven's sake.

Comment: @Thandor7765, a counterexample is a formal proof.

Comment: Thandor: I think you could have posted a higher-quality question: including what you know as the definition of a surjective function (and whether or not you understand the definition) to let us know if we need to refresh your memory...And If you know the definition, then you should have tried to put this specific case to the test.  It's perfectly clear to need and ask for help with that. I simply think you  could have provided more details/context in your question.  Feel free to enrich your question now, or a little bit from now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I say that $f(x,y) = 2$ is not possible.

If we look at the problem modulo $4,$ a perfect square is equivalent to $1$ or $0$ modulo $4.$

$f(x,y)$ reduces to $4$ cases.
$0-0, 1-0, 0-1, 1-1,$  none of which equal $2.$

Comment: I edited it. It is only supposed to be for integers

Comment: Thanks for formatting your answer.  I'll delete my comment now.  No problem.

Comment: @silvascientist I had originally used $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ and showed that it was indeed an injection.  The OP updated the question to state that the domain was integers, and I updated my answer appropriately.

Comment: @DougM Ah, ok. I had thought the OP had the misconception that you proved it only for $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a surjection, though.  Or at least it is if we have $F : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$.

Let $a \in \Bbb{R}$.  Let $y \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $a + y^2 \ge 0$ and let $x = \sqrt{a + y^2}$.  Then we have
$$ F(x,y) = x^2 - y^2 = \left(\sqrt{a+y^2}\right)^2 - y^2 = a + y^2 - y^2 = a$$

Comment: I edited it. It is only supposed to be for all integers

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Suffices to show that there exists $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a = x^2-y^2$ is not true for any $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Could you pick one perhaps?